# GPUImageMovieWriter starting new recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetwriter, gpuimage

Can i reuse an existing `GPUImageMovieWriter` (after calling `finishRecording`) or is there a method to pause and resume the recording?

I get error if i call `startRecoding` after a `finishRecording`.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter addInput:] Cannot call method when status is 2'
```

Comment: see this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911534/avassetwriter-multiple-sessions-and-the-status-property

Comment: Sumit this is not quite the same (despite the same error), i am using GPUImageMovieWriter which wraps AVAssetWriter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `startRecording()` on the same movieWriter instance after calling `finishRecording()`.

`finishRecording()` writes the completion block for the video into file, thus all subsequent frames added to the video file would be useless anyway. If what you want to achieve is to pause recording for a bit and append video at the end again after pausing, you should probably create a "pause" state where you don't record, but simply measure the amount of time paused, and then use an adjusted frame time for when you resume recording again.

Cheers!
Vijay